# Counting downloads from an RPM repository

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, rpm

My company hosts an open source RPM repository and would like to start counting RPM downloads per day.  The repository is hosted on Apache httpd.  Can anyone recommend a good way to count the downloads of just the RPM files (which will have URLs of the form http://packages.mycompany.com/packages/continuous/trunk/fedora/10/RPMS/package1.rpm) while excluding any other accesses to the repository URLs for index browsing, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go with classic apache log analyzers like [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) or [webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/), you might want to try [visitors](http://www.hping.org/visitors/), a simple CLI log file analyzer.

**visitors -o text ACCESS.LOG | grep " /" | grep ".rpm"**

will give you a list of requested RPMs sorted by popularity with the number of downloads included after the file name. Non-RPM downloads will be ignored, so the order might look a little funny.

```
1)    /rpm/example.rpm: 4
3)    /rpm/example2.rpm: 2
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be something along these lines:

grep ".rpm" /var/log/httpd/access_log | wc -l

This would give you the number of files accessed with .rpm in their name.  Simple I know, but effective.